# Send error message on <html:errors> in Action

Tags: java, struts, action, message

I'm doing some operations in my action and want to show an error message when some data input are not in the valid range. We usually do a pre-checking with a javascript method but in this case i can't reach the values of the variables i need to check.

The part of the webpage to show the error message is a strut part

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use form validate method for validating .Before submitting the form it will check your condition.

Example :-

```
public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping,
            HttpServletRequest request) {

         //Write your code for range checking here

            return errors;
    }
```

Except , this method few setting you have to do with `ApplicationResources.property file`